# Glimpse Cache Tab show other Cache Providers, such as Memory Cache

Tags: glimpse

It seems that Glimpse is showing the `HttpRuntime` cache within the Cache tab.  Is there any way, one can natively show other cache providers, such as:

- **Memory Cache** - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx

  - For example, [MVC Donut Caching](https://www.google.com.mt/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmvcdonutcaching.codeplex.com%2F&ei=73dbVMfOEMWtaba4gRg&usg=AFQjCNGvKw5Pq-boxm9TUQ6DB6oJjkHUuA&bvm=bv.78677474,d.d2s&cad=rja) by default uses such Memory Cache and I would like to preview what's inside such a cache through Glimpse
- or any other **Custom cache provider** of our choice?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out-of-the-box only the `HttpRuntime.Cache` is being monitored, but you can create your own tab implementation by implementing the [ITab](https://github.com/glimpse/glimpse/blob/master/source%2FGlimpse.Core%2FExtensibility%2FITab.cs) interface.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, I just asked in case there might be some form of native configuration which I'm not aware of which would work as well with other cache providers.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no common abstraction defined that might cover other possible cache implementations, but even if there were one, then we would still need an implementation of that abstraction for, in this case, the `MemoryCache`, but, either way, feel free to introduce such an abstraction or an `ITab` implementation for the `MemoryCache`, we [accept pull requests](https://github.com/glimpse/glimpse) ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your replies.  Honestly I've never done pull request till now but would be interested :)